# How to launch Front camera in HTML5 without WebRTC?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, webrtc, html-input

I know with `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`, we can launch Gallery/Camera choose option in HTML5 based apps. I would like to launch Front camera to take selfie of the user in my HTML5 app. As iOS does n't support WebRTC, I am searching for any `<input>` attributes that launch front camera. Are there any ways to achieve it.

NOTE: Would like to launch Front camera directly. Launching default rear camera and changing camera face from device camera is not a option here.

Comment: Don't have an iOS under the hand to test it out, but according to this [webkit test page](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/LayoutTests/fast/forms/file/file-input-capture.html), non-standard `capture` attribute should accept `fileSystem`, `microphone`, `camcorder`, and `camera`. But there doesn't seem to be anything about which camera to use.

Answer (score 0):

As per w3c reference (https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/):

> Similarly, the User Agent is advised to offer user control, such as to
>   allow the user to:
>
> 1. select the exact media capture device to be used if there exist multiple devices of the same type (e.g. a front-facing camera in addition to a primary camera).
> 2. disable sound capture when in the video
>      capture mode.

As per this documentation, there is no attribute available as of today to signal which camera to use. In fact as you can read above, the option is given to user agent I.e browser to display an UI which will allow user to choose different options. In case of ios, it selects rear camera by default and give you an option to change it to front camera.